# Why is my iPhone not enabled for iTunes

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore, iphone

Attempting to purchase iTunes for iPhone 6 from Apple Store. Download response indicates iPhone not enabled for iTunes. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Pre-existing Apple ID need to accept the store conditions before downloading. Only if you are creating a new Apple ID can you roll account creation/validation/download into one transaction.

Post an image of your specific error message if this general guidance isn't helpful.